# instalar nvm me tira error

Tags: windows, bash, windows10

Tratando de instalar nvm mediante las instrucciones de su [sitio oficial](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```
PS C:\Users\RuslanLopez> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash
```

> bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:76
>   + ... ttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash
>   +                                                                      ~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

```
PS C:\Users\RuslanLopez> wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash
```

> bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:77
>   + ... ttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash
>   +                                                                      ~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce porque no está instalado bash, la forma más fácil de instalarlo es instalar algún programa que ya lo tenga como por dar algunos ejemplos:

- git
- cygwin

sin embargo, no se debe de correr ese comando en windows, ya que para windows se debe de usar el instalador de https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases